# Integral of $\displaystyle\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{\sin(e^z)}{z^2} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I'm required to solve the integral $\displaystyle\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{\sin(e^z)}{z^2} dz$.

For this, I'm using the Cauchy Integral Theorem which states that
$$f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}} dz$$
under certain conditions that I'm omitting.

Thus,
$$f^{(1)}(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{\sin(e^z)}{z^2} dz \Longrightarrow  2\pi i f'(0) = \int_{\gamma} \frac{\sin(e^z)}{z^2} dz$$
where $f'(z) = \frac{d}{dz} \sin(e^z) = e^z \cos(e^z)$, where it follows that $f'(0) = \cos(1)$.

Therefore,
$$\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{\sin(e^z)}{z^2} dz = 2\pi i\cos(1)$$

It looks correct to me, so I'm just looking for a solution-verification second opinion. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and one can confirm with the residue theorem.

Comment: @user170231 I don't know the residue theorem yet, but I'm looking for it. Thanks!

Comment: Look OK to me. And like @user170231 said you can verify using the residue theorem.